# Coupon code discount prirority issue in magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, coupon

I create 2 coupon codes :
 `coupontest1` which  have the discount 50$ and `priority 0`, and `coupontest2` which  have the discount 40$ and the `priority 10`.

Now if a apply the `first coupon` code with `priority 0` and then apply the `second one` with `priority`10, the second one **override** my coupontest1,which have priority 0 and bigger discount.

With the default Magento core, this it's possible? or it's a bug in my project?

And if  the answer it's no, how can set this? to keep the bigger discount with higher priority and the low priority not override the first one?

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Comment: my verstion it's magento 2.1.3